# Uppercase Accents

Tags: errors, input-encodings

My name is Sebastián and I'm doing my thesis in LaTeX. The last part of my work is the cover, but I have a problem compiling it. I have some uppercase letters with accents in the cover, and I get the following error when I try to compile it:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:�C not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

I think I need another encoding to do this, do you guys know one?

Here is my preamble

```
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

Comment: Sebastián, add a minimal working example (the preamble, and the words and accents which cause the error).

Comment: The most likely cause for this is that the input file is not UTF-8 encoded. Check the setting in your text editor.

Comment: Did you try to insert the accents in formal way, without using the accented characters?

Comment: It looks like you're using something like U+0327 'combining cedilla', which neither pdfLaTeX nor XeLaTeX nor LuaLaTeX seem to like. I recommend using the characters with the cedilla instead (U+00C7 'Latin Capital Letter C With Cedilla') or using the LaTeX command for accents, e.g. `\c{C}`.

Comment: @doncherry inputenc can not cope with combining characters as they are given after the base, but they should work in xelatex/luatex but you shouldn't use `inputenc` with the extended tex engines.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)